# Why is PHP mixing two fopen handles on one file?

Tags: php, file-io, fopen, handle

I noticed while testing two `fopen()` handles on one file, that the handles or channels mix, and the file contents empty when i call `fread()`. One handle is read, and one handle is write.

Example code:

```
$rh = fopen('existingfilewithcontent.txt', 'r');
$wh = fopen('existingfilewithcontent.txt', 'w');
echo fread($rh, 1000);
fclose($rh);
fclose($wh);
// file is now blank
```

This is tested on Linux & Windows.

I could not find anything in the PHP docs about it.

Please do not ask my why I would want  two handles on one file as that is not the question.

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a file for write is destructive.

Manual says:

> **'w'** -  Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

You probably want:

> **'r+'** - Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.

OR

> **'a+'** - Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() only affects the reading position, writes are always appended.

See manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Ah, stupid of me to not catch this. I had assumed the truncate didn't happen until `fwrite()` was called.. Thankyou!